# Use the %username% variable with the PowerShell Set-Location Commandlet

Tags: powershell

In Windows File Explorer, we can use `C:\Users\%username%` but it doesn't work in PowerShell with `Set-Location`.

Is there a way it can with one line?

**File Explorer** - Success

[image: Environmental Variables in the Address Bar]

**Set-Location** - Fail

```
$set-location -path "c:\users\%username%"
set-location : Cannot find path 'C:\users\%username%' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ set-location -path "c:\users\%username%"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 6):

```
# this will do
Set-Location -path "c:\users\$env:username\desktop"

# alternative syntax
cd "c:\users\$env:username\desktop"
```

Answer (score 5):

In powershell, environment variables are accessed via `$ENV:Variable`.

For example:

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\Users\$ENV:UserName"
```

Alternatively, you can use the C# API:

```
Set-Location -Path [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("C:\Users\%Username%")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the tilde ~ character:

```
Set-Location ~
```

or

```
Set-Location "~/My Documents"
```