# How can I add parameters in Powershell to change file destination and version number

Tags: powershell, file, copy

Edit: I have now replaced the user with "$env:username" to correct the first part. Would anyone know how to know add a prompt before running the code to allow a user to type nothing, "A", "B", "C" to replace (version) in the code on the first line?

I completed a code in Powershell to copy files from one destination to the other. I am hoping to make it so when running script, the user can enter their alias and it will replace "alias" in the script. **The second thing would be for the user to enter "A" "B" "C" or nothing in order to replace "(version)" in the script.**

```
#Create New Folders 

new-item -path "C:\Users\$env:username\Archive" -name "TeamsCopy$((get-date).tostring("MMdd"))(version)" -itemtype "directory"

new-item -path "C:\Users\$env:username\Archive\TeamsCopy$((get-date).tostring("MMdd"))\Canada" -itemtype "directory"
 
 
#Copy Files 

Copy-item -path "C:\Users\$env:username\SourceFolder\Canada.xlsx" -destination "C:\Users\alias\Archive\TeamsCopy$((get-date).tostring("MMdd"))\Canada"
```

Does anyone have any idea how to add this in as a prompt and then also the right syntax to use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use the %username% variable with the PowerShell Set-Location Commandlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851240/use-the-username-variable-with-the-powershell-set-location-commandlet)

Comment: To explain the flag- you're asking for how to use parameters, but a better solution for this one is (probably) environment variables

Comment: Agreed on the $env:username, I added that in. How would you recommend I set up the parameter for the user to type "A" "B" "C" or nothing etc.. to replace "version" in the first line? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be `Read-Host`

```bsh
$version = Read-Host "Enter the version (A, B, C or none)"
```

But this bears the risk of invalid user input. Alternatively, you chould [prompt for a choice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) from a fixed list:

```bsh
$title = $null
$prompt = "Choose the version:"
$choices = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] @("&A", "&B", "&C", "&None")
$default = 3
$choice = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $prompt, $choices, $default)
$version = ("A","B","C","")[$choice]
```

And then in your `New-Item` command:

```bsh
-Name "TeamsCopy$((Get-Date).ToString("MMdd"))($version)"
# or
-Name ("TeamsCopy{0:MMdd}({1})" -f (Get-Date), $version)
```